# Firefox sometimes doesn't display image completely in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

At the moment I am trying to display an image in fullscreen via javascript. (Fullscreen API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Javascript code:

```
var enterFullscreen = function(el) {
if(el.requestFullscreen) {
    el.requestFullscreen();
} else if(el.msRequestFullscreen) {
    el.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if(el.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    el.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if(el.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    el.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else {
    noFullscreenSupport();
}

var exitFullscreen = function() {
if(document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
} else if(document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
} else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
} else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
} else {
    noFullscreenSupport();
}

var initFullScreenButtons = function() {
$('.fullScreenButton').each(function(e) {
    $(this).bind('click', function() {
        if((window.innerWidth === screen.width && window.innerHeight === screen.height) || (window.fullScreen)) {
            exitFullscreen();
        } else {
            enterFullscreen(document.documentElement);
        }   
    });
});
```

I get the fullscreen buttons and bind them to a click event which calls the function to enter the fullscreen.

Images:

[Without fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljU4R.png)

[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btx7p.png)

The result is that the image sometimes displays in fullscreen or in a semi-fullscreen, where the background of the page is displayed on the bottom of the page with the width/height of browser-taskbar and windows-taskbar.

Furthermore, as soon as I try to use the developer tool of the browser the visual bug dissappears.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem. Instead of passing `document.documentElement` (root-element) I have to pass `document.body` (body-element) to the function.